# How to display the selected option from listView in the action bar of new activity

Tags: android

Hi i want to implement something like this in action bar or header.
Chapter/Chapter Section/Content

Here Chapter is the main activity . From here When i select "Chapter Section" , I want this to appear on this 2 activity in action bar "Chapter/Chapter Section".
Somewhere similar to breadcrumbs, The difference is link will not be there.

Please Help!
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is it tabs in the actionbar that you are after? The only thing you need to change is that all your content are fragments instead of activities.

To add tabs:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
                // show the given tab
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
                // hide the given tab
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
                // probably ignore this event
            }
// Add 4 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText("TAB " + i)
                            .setTabListener(tabListener));
        }
```

You can read more about it on this page: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: Not Actually Tabs. its just i want to show on what activity the user is , just the path of all activities

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question then. If you want to just write out the path the user has navigated down in your app, you can just set a new text to the actionbar with the path or have TextView just bellow the actionbar that you update when the user is traversing down in your application. For example:

final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("THE PATH");